# How logout from Djoser (installed with Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have installed Djoser with Django Rest Framework, after loggin in as (url :  /token/login ) I receive a token, but when I change url to '/token/logout/ ' it shows error as logging credential not provided.

I am using browser url section to interact with DRF.

Please advice me correct url to logout ? I can provide Token,username and password.

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on this too. What worked for me was to pass the token as normal through the authentication header AND pass it as json data.

```
export const logout = (token) => {
 return url
  .post('api/auth/token/logout/', token,
   {
     headers: {
       Authorization: `Token ${token}`
     }
   })
 .then(res => res.data)
 }
```

Comment: Indeed, we need to pass it trough data too

Answer (score 1):

Have you something like this

```
#urls.py
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work, the following is the error message,            HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="api"

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the Authorization Token with your POST request to the logout URL.

Comment: Try adding this as comment or try elaborating your answer.