# Forbidden: /api/v1/token/logout/ "POST /api/v1/token/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58

Tags: python, html, node.js, django, vue-cli-3

I am experiencing this problem following a tutorial and I can't identify the error in my "MyAccountView.vue" page. I tried changing to re_path and it did not work.

```
Forbidden: /api/v1/token/logout/
[16/Oct/2023 19:01:35] "POST /api/v1/token/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58
```

CODE:

**URLS.PY**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken'))
]
```

**SETTING.PY**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSESS':(
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSESS':(
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

**ERROR IMAGES**

[Getting this error in browser's console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q12Ok.png)

**MyAccountView.vue**

If it works i'm supposed to forward on **"/"** or **home page of my site**.

```
methods: {
        logout() {
            axios
                .post("/api/v1/token/logout/")
                .then(response => {
                    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = ""

                    localStorage.removeItem("token")

                    this.$store.commit('removeToken')

                    this.$router.push('/')
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    if (error.response) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error.response.data))
                    } else if (error.message) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error.message))
                    } else {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
                    }
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your logout view or are you using the default one from Django
?

Comment: I'm using logout() function to logout which is written in upper given MyAccoundView.vue.

Comment: The logout function you have shown in from a vue or a javascript framework. 
I was asking about the logout defined in the server side in Django. Basically whats the corresponding view for `/api/v1/token/logout/`

Comment: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYrRI.png)  and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl5xG.png)
check out these images 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `djoser`

You need to pass the token while calling the logout endpoint in your Post request

Example:

```
.post('api/v1/token/logout/', token,
   {
     headers: {
       Authorization: `Token ${token}`  --> Add your token here.
     }
   })
```

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please use this token as an example "a24d89afd0730e8b141ae7a6e398d6769216ef8b"?

Comment: You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67411706/9544403)

Comment: You should check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77309041/getting-error-detailauthentication-credentials-were-not-provided-on-making)