# Getting error "detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, djoser

I tried to get the username corresponding to the auth_token but getting this error.
I followed the [djoser's documentation](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_usage.html)

ERROR:

```
PS D:\test\testenv\test2> curl.exe -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/ --data 'username=admin3&password=password@123'
{"username":["A user with that username already exists."]}
PS D:\test\testenv\test2> curl.exe -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/token/login/ --data 'username=admin3&password=password@123'
{"auth_token":"3d0ad33f20ea22e8131a170da2db7830a18b3757"}
PS D:\test\testenv\test2> curl.exe -LX GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/me/ -H 'Authorization: Token 3d0ad33f20ea22e8131a170da2db7830a18b3757'
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
PS D:\test\testenv\test2> curl.exe -LX GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/ -H 'Authorization: Token 3d0ad33f20ea22e8131a170da2db7830a18b3757'
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
PS D:\test\testenv\test2>
```

It should return me the token's corresponding details.